# Changing element in pandas based on string in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Data Frame with 2 columns. One is 'image' which contains a string for a file path and the other is 'target' which needs to contain either a 1 or a 0.

How can I change the 'target' to 1 or 0 based on a part of the string in 'image'?

i.e. if 'image' contains '1_' then the target will be 1. if 'image' contains '0_' then the target will be 0.

Since the data frame looks like this

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMR95.png)

I know I can just do something like...

```
df['target'][0:363] = 1
df['target'][364:] = 0
```

...in this case. But for future reference in other DFs that aren't in I would like to find out how to do it in a more efficient way.

Comment: Does this work? `df['target'] = df['image'].str.split('_', n=1)[0].astype(int)`

Comment: No, that added the file name to the target too. Although its close.

I got it done in two lines of code with
`df.loc[df['image'].str.contains('1_'), 'target'] =1`

`df.loc[df['image'].str.contains('0_'), 'target'] =0`

although there has to be a way to one line it...

Comment: If the image filename always starts with either the 1 or the 0 like it does in your example, you could just slice the first character from the string.